# How to animate a dropdown menu using CSS3 animations?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, animate.css

I would like to add a CSS3 effect to my dropdown. (Just like that one in Instagram.com on "My profile").

I'm using [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) for the CSS3 effects.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="dropdownalerts" data-options="is_hover:true"><%=fa_icon "bell"%></a>

<ul id="dropdownalerts" class="f-dropdown text-left animated bounceInDown" data-dropdown-content>
   <li><%=link_to "Facebook", "#"%></li>
   <li><%=link_to "Email", "#" %></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').hover(function(){
        $("ul").addClass('animated bounceInDown');
    });
});
```

You can find a live version on [Zapping.io](http://zapping.io)

Comment: I'm not being rude but can you confirm you are referencing the `animate.min.css` file?

Comment: yes, in other "divs" it works

Comment: I think the problem is that "animate.css" should fires when dropdown is clicked and then menu is opened

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got it working in an example. I used the HTML you provided, and then downloaded the `bounceInDown` animation and used that for the CSS in the examples below.

[**jsFiddle example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/6BSM3/) - hover method

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').hover(function() {
    $("ul").addClass('animated bounceInDown');
  },function(){
    $("ul").removeClass('animated bounceInDown');
  });
});
```

If you want to add a delay when hovering off, use something like this:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/KR22Q/) - hover method with delay.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').hover(function() {
    $("ul").addClass('animated bounceInDown');
  },function(){setTimeout(function(){
    $("ul").removeClass('animated bounceInDown');
  }, 750);});
});
```

---

Those examples are assuming you want the animation fired on hover. If you want it fired on click, use something like this instead:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/K3SUE/3/) click method - Look below for an alternative non-JS method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function() {
    $("ul").toggleClass('animated bounceInDown');
  });
});
```

---

## Alternative method -  No JS/jQuery

If you don't want to use JavaScript/jQuery, you can use the checkbox hack in CSS.

This essentially toggles between `:checked`, thus activating the animation.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dczAu/) - It works in all current browsers.

**HTML**

```
<label id="click" for="dropdown">Click here</label>
<input style="display:none" type="checkbox" id="dropdown">
<ul id="dropdownalerts" class="f-dropdown text-left" data-dropdown-content>
    <li>Facebook</li>
    <li>Email</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS** - <sub>(only part of it) See the example above for full CSS.</sub>

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #dropdownalerts {
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: bounceInDown 1s both;
    -moz-animation: bounceInDown 1s both;
    -o-animation: bounceInDown 1s both;
    animation: bounceInDown 1s both;
}
```